# How to unstring a list/tuple without eval

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to use `input` to get the value for a tuple. However, since `input` sets the value as a string, I'm trying to *unstring* it as well. I've found that `eval` works for this purpose, but that it should be [distrusted.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2013-June/096234.html) While this will not be a problem as long as I use the code privately, if I were to publicly release it I want to use the best code possible.

So, is there another way of unstringing a `tuple` in Python 3?

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
>>> a = input("What is the value? ")
What is the value? (3,4)
>>> a
'(3,4)'
>>> eval(a)
(3, 4)
```

Comment: You could try to get two values (I assume you want a tuple, not a N-tuple) like this `a, b = map(int, input().split())` where `a` and `b` are separated by space.

Comment: Why not get the user to type something simpler, like `3, 4` without the brackets?

Comment: @101 because this code will be used for cartesian coordinates (many of them). I find it easier to group the coordinates together. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the safe version of eval, `ast.literal_eval` which is designed exactly for what you are trying to achieve:

```
from ast import literal_eval
tup = literal_eval(a)
```

Comment: This solution is awesome and quick!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this:

```
>>> inp = input()
'(3,4)'
>>> tuple(map(int, inp.strip()[1:-1].split(',')))
(3, 4)
```

where `strip` will make sure leading or trailing blanks won't ruin your day.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went ahead and accepted @Padraic Cunningham 's answer since it was simpler and worked with lists too (which I needed) but I'll keep your answer in mind for future code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you don't ask the user to input a tuple.  Instead you do this:

```
x = input("Enter x value: ")
y = input("Enter y value: ")

data = (
    int(x),
    int(y)
)

print( 
    repr(data)
)

--output:--
(10, 3)
```

Comment: That won't really work for my code--it's Euclidean-geometry based, and has a lot of cartesian coords that I find easier to keep grouped together. Thanks anyway!